# bundle exec tapioca init for sorbet throws error

Tags: sorbet

I'm trying to adopt sorbet into my pre-existing project. I get to the 3rd step of their adoption instructions. I can't get `bundle exec tapioca init` to run. Anyone have any ideas?

```
bundler: failed to load command: tapioca (/Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/tapioca)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    31: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
    30: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
    29: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
    28: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:103:in `with_friendly_errors'
    27: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
    26: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
    25: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    24: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
    23: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    22: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    21: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    20: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:484:in `exec'
    19: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    18: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    17: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.3.7/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    16: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/tapioca:23:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/bin/tapioca:23:in `load'
    14: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/exe/tapioca:21:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/exe/tapioca:21:in `require_relative'
    12: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/lib/tapioca/internal.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/lib/tapioca/internal.rb:4:in `require'
    10: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/lib/tapioca.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/lib/tapioca.rb:48:in `require'
     8: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/lib/tapioca/compilers/dsl/base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/lib/tapioca/compilers/dsl/base.rb:4:in `require'
     6: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/lib/tapioca/rbi_ext/model.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/tapioca-0.6.2/lib/tapioca/rbi_ext/model.rb:4:in `require'
     4: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rbi-0.0.13/lib/rbi.rb:24:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rbi-0.0.13/lib/rbi.rb:24:in `require'
     2: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rbi-0.0.13/lib/rbi/parser.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rbi-0.0.13/lib/rbi/parser.rb:20:in `<module:RBI>'
/Users/hellendou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rbi-0.0.13/lib/rbi/parser.rb:28:in `<class:Parser>': undefined method `emit_arg_inside_procarg0=' for Parser::Builders::Default:Class (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  emit_procarg0=
```

Comment: You appear to be encountering https://github.com/Shopify/rbi/pull/126
Is your `parser` version at least 2.6.4.0 ?

Comment: It says that tapioca wants a parser (>= 2.3.1.2, < 2.6)

Comment: ```
    tapioca was resolved to 0.6.2, which depends on
      rbi (~> 0.0.0, >= 0.0.9) was resolved to 0.0.13, which depends on
        unparser was resolved to 0.4.2, which depends on
          parser (>= 2.3.1.2, < 2.6)
```

Comment: I think you need a newer release of `rbi` to resolve this then.